# How to get multi-dimension specific data samples on the basis of list element?

Tags: python, numpy, random, numpy-ndarray, lis

I need to evaluate my model's performance with limited training data. I am randomly selecting p of original training data. Assume p is 0.2 in this case. Here is some intil lines of code:

```
p = p*100
data_samples = (data.shape[0] * p)/100  # data.shape= (100, 50, 50, 3)

# for randomly selecting data
import random
random.seed(1234)
filter_indices=[random.randrange(0, data.shape[0]) for _ in range(data_samples)]
```

Its giving me total filter indices randomly ranging between 0 and total data size.

Now, I want to get those samples of indices from the 'data' that are equivalent to filter_indices but include all dimensions. How can I do that effectively and effeciently?

Comment: You should be able to index `data` like: `out = data[filter_indices]`. Also note that you can use numpy's random module to streamline your code. Consider: `N = data.shape[0]; filter_indices = np.random.choice(N, size=int(N * p))`.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs thank you so much for your comment. Sorry for late reply. How can we use seed with `filter_indices = np.random.choice(N, size=int(N * p))`.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs I used `np.random.seed(0)` right before `filter_indices = np.random.choice(N, size=int(N * p))`. I believe it's working. Thank you so much for your help. If you want to post your comment in a formal answer, please go ahead. I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy's [integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to use your generated list of indices directly as index. When used on its own, the trailing dimensions will automatically be tacked on to the result! Smaller example:

```
import numpy as np

# Your data goes here
data = np.arange(90).reshape(10, 3, 3)

N = data.shape[0]
p = 0.2

# Generating random indices
n_samples = int(N * p)
np.random.seed(0)
filter_indices = np.random.choice(N, size=n_samples)

# Indexing magic:
out = data[filter_indices]
```

Note above that I've used numpy's built-in random module to streamline your code a little bit via [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

Results:

```
>>> filter_indices
array([5, 0])
>>> out
array([[[45, 46, 47],
        [48, 49, 50],
        [51, 52, 53]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]]])
>>> out.shape
(2, 3, 3)
```

`out` is exactly the 2 shape `(3, 3)` subarrays in `data` at indices 5 and 0. So the result has shape `(2, 3, 3)` instead of `(10, 3, 3)`.